# Adding/Configuring the Subject Alternative Name of the CA certificate in Hyperledger Fabric CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have a couple of Hyperledger Fabric networks (1.4 and 2.3+ versions) working OK but I have a annoying configuration problem with the CA.

The certificate for the CA that my artifacts generate (configtx.yaml) and (crypto-config.yaml) has as CN value "ca.myorg.org". This means that the CA only accepts requests to that host address. If I do a request to host "ca" (which is the host name created by the Kubernetes cluster) I get:

"hyperledger client doesn't match any of the subject alternative names" error from the CA instance.

I use Kubernetes to deploy the network and the service name are "ca", "peer1", ...
so I cannot simply set ca.myorg.org as service name... this implies that I have to:

1. Add a custom DNS alias in the Kubernetes inner DNS to map ca -> ca.myorg.org so I can run requests to ca.myorg.org from the Chaincode Java client pod. (requests to "ca" will be rejected by CA.
2. When I run tests from outside the Kubernetes network, I need to use Kubefwd, which is OK, but that will create a local hosts entry "ca" in my computer... everytime I need to manually add that alias too to the hosts file. Very annoying.

My question is... how can I configure the artifacts so "ca" is also accepted as a Subject Alternative Name in the generated certificate for the CA? That would solve my problem.

As a work around, can I also alter the certificate adding the "ca" subject alternative name, after it's generated? That would work.

Of course, maybe I am missing something on all this artifact certificate generation when creating the Hyperledger Fabric network. I'm all ears for suggestions on what approach to take when the CA is going to be deployed in Kubernetes.

Comment: IMHO, at this point you should stop using Fabric CA and generate your own CA using openSSL. Fabric CA is just a scripted openSSL and it is hard to customize them with the limited control given to user. By generating yourself, the SAN DNS is totally in your control which you can set the public IP address and DNS (No need to set in hosts file anymore).

Comment: Thanks. All I do is follow all tutorials that generate the configuration files and certifiates based on crypto-config.yaml and configtx.yaml files. (they all use those 2 files and commands). Do you have any reference on how to generate a specific certificate file for my Fabric CA instance?